# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'picamera'

Tags: python, attributes, raspberry-pi, attributeerror

I'm climbing the learning curve with my kids using a project involving rabbits (original project: hamster cam, http://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/hamster-party-cam/worksheet.md). We've followed the instructions to arrive at the program below.

When we run it, it gives this rather vague error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/pi/hkop.py", line 12, in <module>
     with picamera.picamera() as camera:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'picamera'
```

Can anyone help us resolve this?

```
import pibrella, picamera, time, random, os, sys

colours = [pibrella.light.red, pibrella.light.amber, pibrella.light.green]

def disco():
    for i in range(25):
        result = random.choice(colours)
        result.on
        time.sleep(0.2)
        result.off()

with picamera.picamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
    pic= 1
    while True:
       if pibrella.input.a.read():
       camera.capture ('/home/pi/konijn/image%03d.jpg' % pic)
       print("Hoera!")
       os.system ('omxplayer 1-39-gcn-dk-mountain.mp3 &')
       disco()
       time.sleep(20)
       pic += 1
       time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: @Plouff, the name is wrong there is only Picamera not picamera

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.9/api.html#picamera.PiCamera), the class is `picamera.PiCamera`. So, your `with` line should be:

```
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    ...
```

Also, as Padraic Cunningham pointed out, in your `disco()` function, the line

```
result.on
```

should actually be

```
result.on()
```

as you're calling a function of the `result` object.

Answer (score 1):

```
picamera.PiCamera()
```

not:

```
picamera.piCamera()
```

and you should use:

```
subprocess.Popen
```

instead of :

```
os.system
```